# What happens if I get addicted to whiskey in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

The in-game text implies that it is possible to get addicted to the various alcoholic and medical substances found in Fallout 3. I'm curious - what are the consequences of addiction and can they be counteracted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whiskey has a base 10% chance to give you an addiction which increases each time you consume it.

Upon becoming addicted, withdrawal from Whiskey will give you a penalty of -1 agility and -1 charisma.

In Fallout 3, addictions are permanent until cured by:

- visiting a doctor
- owning and using a My First Laboratory house improvement in a house you own
- using healing archways in Mothership Zeta

Further details about addictions for all the Fallout games can be found on the Fallout Wiki [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Addiction)

Comment: Do you get addicted to Whiskey specifically or will any alcoholic drink in general sate the addiction?

Comment: It'll be Whiskey specifically, it's an odd quirk of the FO3 addiction system.

Comment: Thanks that's interesting - also that some drugs have a higher chance of addiction than others :)